# Building API Manager from source fails

Tags: wso2

I'm trying to build the API Manager from source according to the documentation at http://docs.wso2.org/wiki/display/AM130/Obtaining+the+Product#ObtainingtheProduct-source

I did `svn checkout http://svn.wso2.org/repos/wso2/carbon/platform/tags/4.0.3/products/apimgt/1.2.0 wso2carbon`

Then I did `"mvn clean install -Dproduct=apimgt"`

I'm using maven 3 and Java 6. I'm getting the error below; any ideas on what's wrong and how I can build the source?...

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.wso2.maven:carbon-p2-plugin:1.5:p2-profile-ge
n (3-p2-profile-generation) on project am-p2-profile: P2 publisher return code w
as 13 -> [Help 1]
org.apache.maven.lifecycle.LifecycleExecutionException: Failed to execute goal o
rg.wso2.maven:carbon-p2-plugin:1.5:p2-profile-gen (3-p2-profile-generation) on p
roject am-p2-profile: P2 publisher return code was 13
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor
.java:217)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor
.java:153)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor
.java:145)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProje
ct(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:84)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProje
ct(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:59)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.singleThreadedBu
ild(LifecycleStarter.java:183)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute(Lifecycl
eStarter.java:161)
        at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:320)
        at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(DefaultMaven.java:156)
        at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute(MavenCli.java:537)
        at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain(MavenCli.java:196)
        at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main(MavenCli.java:141)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.
java:39)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAcces
sorImpl.java:25)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced(Laun
cher.java:290)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch(Launcher.jav
a:230)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode(La
uncher.java:409)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:
352)
Caused by: org.apache.maven.plugin.MojoExecutionException: P2 publisher return c
ode was 13
        at org.wso2.maven.p2.ProfileGenMojo.execute(ProfileGenMojo.java:171)
        at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo(Default
BuildPluginManager.java:101)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor
.java:209)
        ... 19 more
Caused by: org.apache.maven.plugin.MojoFailureException: P2 publisher return cod
e was 13
        at org.wso2.maven.p2.ProfileGenMojo.installFeatures(ProfileGenMojo.java:
213)
        at org.wso2.maven.p2.ProfileGenMojo.execute(ProfileGenMojo.java:164)
        ... 21 more
```

Comment: You can not build from that svn link. You have to take up from this link http://svn.wso2.org/repos/wso2/carbon/ and specifically you need to build orbit/kernal/platform  for the relavant versions... But wondering why are you trying to build the source (it is bit difficult for a newbie)? are you trying to do any customization?

Comment: I'm trying to gain more insight into the architecture of the API Manager. I'll try the link you presented.

Comment: You can build the product from the above link..But if some jars are not hosted at our repo then you cannot. So, building from orbit/kernal/platform will work. Can you try build the product with the chkout oyu got  from the link which you provided using this command.# mvn clean install -Dmaven.test.skip=true

Comment: And if you like to get more insight about the architecture/implemenattion you need to checkout the code from here http://svn.wso2.org/repos/wso2/carbon/. You wont get code from the following link  http://svn.wso2.org/repos/wso2/carbon/platform/tags/4.0.3/products/apimgt/1.2.0/